# VERSION_TIMESTAMP where can I find definition?

Tags: c, linux

In:

```
#define VERSION_TIMESTAMP __DATE__" "__TIME__"\x0"
```

exists components: "**__DATE__**" and "**__TIME__**"

Where can I find definition of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are defined in C and [implemented in gcc as Standard Predefined Macros](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html):

> The standard predefined macros are specified by the relevant language standards, so they are available with all compilers that implement those standards. Older compilers may not provide all of them. Their names all start with double underscores.

Comment: OK, as I understand, I can't expect one format of the date. May be "Nov 24 2015" or other, right?

Comment: I see answer in @user694733 post

Answer (score 1):

Definitions can be found in C standard (from N1570):

> #### 6.10.8.1 Mandatory macros
>
> 1 The following macro names shall be defined by the implementation:
>
> **__DATE__** The date of translation of the preprocessing translation unit: a character
>   string literal of the form **"Mmm dd yyyy"**, where the names of the
>   months are the same as those generated by the **asctime** function, and the
>   first character of **dd** is a space character if the value is less than 10. If the
>   date of translation is not available, an implementation-defined valid date
>   shall be supplied.
>
> ...
>
> **__TIME__** The time of translation of the preprocessing translation unit: a character
>   string literal of the form **"hh:mm:ss"** as in the time generated by the
>   **asctime** function. If the time of translation is not available, an
>   implementation-defined valid time shall be supplied.